# If a continuous function takes equal values at endpoints, in cannot be injective in the interior

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> Suppose $f$ is a nonconstant continuous function on $[0,2]$ and satisfies $f(0)=f(2)=0$. Show $f$ cannot be one to one on the open interval $(0,2)$.

I'm a little confused about this question. If $f(0)=f(2)=0$, then shouldn't the function be one to one?

Comment: You're forgetting the continuity property of $f$ somewhere in your question.

Comment: @tryss since 0 and 2 aren't included in the interval, shouldn't this function be one to one?

Answer (score 3):

The idea of the question is: I have a continuous function that verify $f(0)=f(2)=0$, so it's not one-to-one. But can such a function be one-to-one everywhere else (i.e. on $]0,2[$)?

The answer is no.

Short proof :

Suppose without loss of generality that there exists $a\in (0,2)$ such that $f(a) > 0$. By the intermediate value theorem

1) there exists $b\in (0,a)$ such that $f(b) = \frac{f(a)}{2}$,

2) there exists $c\in (a,2)$ such that $f(c) = \frac{f(a)}{2}$,

so there exists $b,c \in (0,2)$, $b\neq c$ such that $f(b)=f(c)$.

Hence $f$ is not one to one.

Comment: To use the mean value theorem you need to assume that $f$ is differentiable not just continuous.

Comment: @tryss so even though 0 and 2 are not included in the interval, they cause the function not to be one to one on $(0,2)$?

Comment: @RobArthan : sorry, I meant intermediate value theorem, I always forget the name. I'll correct

Comment: @RyanT.Donnelly : indeed. Intuitively, the idea is that when you go up, you'll be forced to go down, and pass by the same "altitude" on the descent than on the climb. This is caused by the condition of continuity of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a continuous function on an interval is one-to-one iff it is either monotonic increasing or monotonic decreasing (why? - use the intermediate value theorem). How can a function $f : (0, 2) \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $0$ and as $x$ tends to $2$, be monotonic increasing or monotonic decreasing?

Comment: So using the fact that the function returns to 0 proves that the function is neither monotonic increasing or decreasing,

Comment: That's right, but you need to do a bit of work with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to prove that.