# Continuous $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(0)=f(1)$ and $\forall\alpha\in(0,1)\exists c\in[0,1-\alpha]|f(c)=f(c+\alpha)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Is it true that $\forall\alpha\in(0,1)\exists c\in[0,1-\alpha]|f(c)=f(c+\alpha)$?

At first I tried to find a counterexample but my intuition says it's true.
Then I've got the idea of applying Bolzano's Theorem to $g(x)=f(x)-f(x+\alpha)$ defined on $[0,1-\alpha]$  but I didn't get anything. What can I do?

Comment: This is definitely helpful to you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536042/if-a-continuous-function-takes-equal-values-at-endpoints-in-cannot-be-injective

Comment: See [Construct a continuous function $f$ over $[0,1]$ satisfying $f(0) = f(1)$ but $f(x) \neq f(x+a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670457/construct-a-continuous-function-f-over-0-1-satisfying-f0-f1-but-f) and the linked [Show that for any positive integer $n$ there is $x \in [0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ for which $f(x) = f(x+\frac{1}{n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668804/show-that-for-any-positive-integer-n-there-is-x-in-0-1-frac1n-for-wh).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you choose $$f(x):= \begin{cases} x &: x < \frac{1}{4} \\
                       \frac{1}{2}-x &:  \frac{1}{4}\leqslant x\leqslant \frac{3}{4} \\
                     x-1 &: \frac{3}{4}\leqslant x \leqslant 1\end{cases}$$ and $\alpha=\frac{3}{4}$ then $f(x)\geq 0$ and $f(x+\alpha)\leqslant 0$ for all $x\in [0,1-\alpha]$.

Comment: Exceedingly clever construction, I love it.

Comment: Can such examples also be given for "small" $\alpha$?

Comment: I suspect that the question statement is true if $\alpha\leq 1/2$.

Comment: The two questions and their answers linked by dxiv in the comments give a complete answer to this. The statement is true iff $\alpha =1/n$, otherwise there are examples like this.

Comment: @MichaelLee The linked thread has an answer that claims to construct an $f$ that works to disprove your suspicion for a given $\alpha$ as long as $\alpha$ is not of the form $1/n$ for some whole number $n$. _(while typing)_ Torsten's comment above just said it.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $f(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$ and $1/2 < \alpha < 1$. Then, $f(x)\geq 0$ and $f(x+\alpha)\leq 0$ for all $x\in [0, 1-\alpha]$.